# IdentityServer3 + AzureAD and RedirectUri Confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, azure-active-directory, identityserver3

I'm struggling to understand how IdentityServer3, AzureAD and a Private Database all work together. The biggest problem is how the Redirect URIs are being handled.

My scenario is I have a stand alone IdentityServer3. It's job is to authenticate users against either AzureAD or a private DB. Within the Startup.cs file on the ID3 server, I have the following OpenID Connect code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/identity", s3App =>
        {
            s3App.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
            {
                SiteName = "3S",
                SigningCertificate = Certificate.Load(),

                Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
                                .UseInMemoryUsers(InMemoryUsers.Get())
                                .UseInMemoryClients(InMemoryClients.Get())
                                .UseInMemoryScopes(InMemoryScopes.Get()),

                AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions
                {
                    EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect = true,
                    EnableSignOutPrompt = false,
                    IdentityProviders = ConfigureAdditionalIdentityProviders
                }
            });
        });
    }

    public static void ConfigureAdditionalIdentityProviders(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
    {
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "AzureAd",
            Caption = "Login",
            ClientId = "4613ed32-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx", // GUID of registered application on Azure
            Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/our-tenant-id/",

            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44348/identity",
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44348/identity",

            Scope = "openid email profile",
            ResponseType = "id_token",
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                AuthenticationType = Constants.ExternalAuthenticationType,
                ValidateIssuer = false
            }
        });
    }
```

I don't understand why the ID3 Server would need to have either RedirectUri or PostLogoutRedirectUri...shouldn't that be "passed through" from the application requesting the authentication? After all, we want to get back to the application, not the ID3 Server. Granted, I don't think this is what's causing my problem, but it would be nice to understand why these are here.

I will say, I've gotten "close" to this working.

When my application requiring authentication requests authentication against AzureAD, I'm redirected to the Microsoft Account login screen to enter my username/password for my work account. I submit my credentials and then get redirected back to either the ID3 server or my application, depending on which RedirectUri has been used in the above code.

For the sake of argument, let's say I use my application for the RedirectUri. I will be sent back to the application, but not to the page that initially prompted the authentication challenge, and if I click on a page that requires authentication, I'm sent back to the AzureAD server to log in again, only this time AzureAD recognizes me as already logged in.

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that the SecurityTokenValidated notification is being acknowledged/set after the redirect from AzureAD.

Here's the code found in the application Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
             AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://localhost:44348/identity",
            ClientId = "3af8e3ba-5a04-4acc-8c51-1d30f8587ced", // Local ClientID registered as part of the IdentityServer3 InMemoryClients
            Scope = "openid profile roles",
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:52702/",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:52702/",
            ResponseType = "id_token",

            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            UseTokenLifetime = false,

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
                {
                    var id = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                    var givenName = id.FindFirst(Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName);
                    var familyName = id.FindFirst(Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName);
                    var sub = id.FindFirst(Constants.ClaimTypes.Subject);
                    var roles = id.FindAll(Constants.ClaimTypes.Role);

                    var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(
                        id.AuthenticationType,
                        Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName,
                        Constants.ClaimTypes.Role
                        );

                    nid.AddClaim(givenName);
                    nid.AddClaim(familyName);
                    nid.AddClaim(sub);
                    nid.AddClaims(roles);

                    nid.AddClaim(new Claim("application_specific", "Some data goes here. Not sure what, though."));
                    nid.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                    n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(nid, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },

                RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                {
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType != OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                        return Task.FromResult(0);

                    var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");

                    if (idTokenHint != null)
                    {
                        n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },

                AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                {
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Error/message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                    //Debug.WriteLine("*** AuthenticationFailed");
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },

            }
        });

        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = Constants.ClaimTypes.Subject;
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
}
```

You'll notice that the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions also contain a RedirectUri and a PostLogoutRedirectUri which point to the application, but those don't seem to matter.

Of course, everything works perfectly when I'm logging in using the "cookies" side of things - I see all of my claims for the user. And, spending some time on the phone with Microsoft, they proposed a solution outside of ID3 which worked, but is not the way we need to go. We will have multiple applications authenticating against our ID3 so we need to contain and control the flow internally.

I really need some help trying to figure out this last mile issue. I know I'm close, I've just been staring at this so long that I'm probably staring right at my error and not seeing it.

**10/22/2016 Edit**
Further testing and enabling Serilog revealed an issue with the `RedirectUri` and `PostLogoutRedirectUri` resulted in my adding the `/identity` to the end of the URIs which corresponds to the value set in app.Map. This resolved the issue of my being returned to the "blank" page of IdentityServer3, I'm now returned to the IdentityServer3 login screen. Azure AD still thinks I'm logged in, I'm just not getting the tokens set properly in my application.

Answer (score 3):

Since the authenticate flow is a little complex, I am trying illustrate it using a figure below:
[image]

First the redirect URL need to register to the identity provider, so the server will match the RedirectURL in request to ensure that the response is redirected as expected instead of redirect to like Phishing site( security consideration).

And as the figure demonstrate, to use the Azure AD as the external identity provider for IdentityServer3,  we need to register the apps on Azure AD. However since the app is used to communicate with Identity Server, the redirect URL register on the Azure Portal should redirect to the IdentityServer3 instead of URL of app.

For example,  the URL of my identity server 3 is https://localhost:44333 then I use code below to add the additional identity providers. And this URL is the redirect URL on the Azure portal:

```
public static void ConfigureAdditionalIdentityProviders(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
{
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "aad",
            Caption = "Azure AD",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,

            Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/04e14a2c-0e9b-42f8-8b22-3c4a2f1d8800",
            ClientId = "eca61fd9-f491-4f03-a622-90837bbc1711",
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44333/core/aadcb",
        });
}
```

And the URL of my app is http://localhost:1409/ which is register on the IdentyServer3 and below code is the web app use OWIN OpenId Connect to add the IdentyServer3 as the identity data provider:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
      AuthenticationType = "oidc",
      SignInAsAuthenticationType = "cookies",
      Authority = "https://localhost:44333",
      ClientId = "mvc",
      RedirectUri = "http://localhost:1409/",
      ResponseType = "id_token",
      Scope = "openid profile email"
});
```

Comment: I used your illustration and code snips to change/verify the code I'm using. Unfortunately, the same issue is happening...once I authenticate against Azure AD I'm redirected to the IdentityServer3, not to my application as desired. I've also verified that the client in IdentityServer3 has the correct RedirectUris and PostLogoutRedirectUris. I just never make it back to my application.

Comment: Since the test above working for me well, I suggest that you track the HTTP request/redirection/response through **Fiddler** to see whether there is the error message when the request was redirected to Identity Server3.

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT in your example for the RedirectUri is there an endpoint defined (API or Controller) for '/aadcb'? Or can the RedirectUri be anything /core/<not_real>?

Comment: No, this endpoint is used to validate the response from AAD. For the latest IdentityServer to sign-in with external provider, you can refer to the official document below:
https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signin_external_providers.html?highlight=provider